# Is an ideal generated by a compact subset finitely generated?

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra, compactness, topological-groups

Let $R$ be a commutative topological ring and let $K$ be a compact subset of $R$. Denote by $I$ the ideal generated by $K$.

Then is it true (or under what assumptions on $R$ (besides Noetherianity) is it true) that $I$ is a finitely generated ideal?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general.  An easy source of counterexamples is Banach algebras.  For instance, let $R$ be the ring of continuous functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, with the topology given by the sup norm $\|f\|=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$.  Let $f_n(x)=\max(0,x-1/n)$ and let $g_n=f_n/n$.  Then the sequence $(g_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $0$ in $R$, so $K=\{g_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\cup\{0\}$ is compact.  The ideal $I$ generated by $K$ is not finitely generated, since a generator could only vanish when every $g_n$ vanishes (i.e., only at $0$), but every element of $I$ vanishes on an entire neighborhood of $0$.